# Has no method issue jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a plugin for simple templating, though I have not yet even begun...

I keep getting the following Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,n){return new x.fn.init(e,n,t)} has no method 'tmpl'
```

the plugin code as it stands currently is:

```
$.fn.tmpl = function(template, options)
{

    var defaults = {
        file: '',
        callback: function(){}
    }

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    function parse()
    {



    }

};
```

This is how I call the function:

```
var template = $.tmpl('user-profile-feed-item');
```

I have jQuery 2.0.1 included it's above the reference for this file, and this file is being loaded, But it just doesn't want to work, and I'm out of ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo without errors`](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4aHZ/)***

You attached `tmpl` to the jQuery prototype. You can only access the prototype if you instantiate a jQuery object. In other words, you need to call jQuery

```
var template = $().tmpl('user-profile-feed-item');
```

---

Edit

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/aPvuW/)***

Here is a sample of the code you used that might help point out some of the uses of extending the jQuery prototype.

```
$.fn.tmpl = function(template, options)
{
 var me = this;//this will refer to the current jQuery object, console.log(this) to see more
 var defaults = {
    file: '',
    callback: function(){}
 };

 var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

 defaults.parse = function()
 {
  alert(me.html());
 };

 return defaults;

};
var template = $("#d").tmpl('user-profile-feed-item');
template.parse();
```

Comment: @AndréFigueira - That is because nothing is returned in your function.

Comment: Ah I see, ok, still unable to call that function (parse), Guessing that's not the right way then.

Comment: @AndréFigueira - Here, this might help you out a little: http://jsfiddle.net/aPvuW/

Answer (score 2):

You want to create jQuery function not plugin. It could be like this

```
$.tmpl = function(template, options)
{

    var defaults = {
        file: '',
        callback: function(){}
    }

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    function parse()
    {



    }

};
```

Comment: Still getting undefined even with this.

Comment: @AndréFigueira the way you are calling you will get undefined because you need to return something from the function. By default it returns undefined.